# React Native ScrollView needs very violent scrolling to scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-scrollview

On Android (and possibly iOS, I haven't tested), there is a problem with scrolling text with a React Native Scrollview. I am attempting to create a text block component that flexes to fill the remaining space of the page with text rendered inside of it. That works.

My problem is that this text needs to be easily scrollable. In my application, I can not make minor scrolling adjustments to the text in this field. (Think about scrolling on Instagram, you can scroll up or down in very small gestures).

This text in the scrollview does not scroll unless you give it a very long and quick flick of the finger. It does scroll and it scrolls correctly functionality-wise, the user experience is just awful.

It's as if it doesn't get recognized as a scroll view unless you scroll it a massive amount.

This happens with normal text elements getting passed into props.children. I am just setting fontSize on the text elements so that the text is bigger. Right now the text font size is set to 60 so that I can test the scrolling functionality.

Here is my text block code:

```
const TextBlock = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={{...props.style, ...styles.container}}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
                {props.children}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.whiteBackgroundColor,
        paddingHorizontal: 18,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 20,
        width: '90%',
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I've tried putting a flex grow on the inner elements. I have tried wrapping the inside text in another view (both with and without flex attributes). I have tried removing the flex altogether.

Please let me know if there's some way to fix this.